# Can't get access to custom UIView property

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access

I have `UIView` subclass

```
class GraphView: UIView {
    var test = false
}
```

And when I'm trying to get access to the `test` property via `@IBOutlet`, I get `exc_bad_access` error.

What is my problem?

Comment: you mean you cant access test var, when GraphView is declared as IBOutlet property ? Where and how u declared the IBOUtlet ?

Comment: I had connected GraphView via storyboard into controller

Comment: Did you intialize GraphView because test doesn't look like a class variable

Comment: have you set the class in the identity inspector of storyboard?

Comment: `class TableData: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: GraphView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        graphView.test = true
     }
`

Comment: your question is not clear. you are accessing test property via @IBOutlet means what? write necessary code and information

Comment: Yes, I set identity in storyboard

Comment: @Danilll Gavrilov, try changing name of variable to something else. A lot of times it could be your runtime compiler trying to access another object with the variable called test. resulting in the error.

Comment: @NSGangster nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be, you are trying to access the property of the @IBOutlet before the view has loaded.@IBOutlet is initialised only when view containing the outlet is loaded.

Comment: I am trying to get access in `ViewDidLoad` method

Comment: could you test the same in `ViewDidAppear`

Comment: I tested this also in `tableView(didSelectRowAtIndexPath)`

Comment: is the class specified in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue. It turned out the viewController's view was connected to the IBOutlet, instead of my custom view